# Error 500 al generar documento PDf con dompdf en Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf, laravel-10

Tengo una parte del proyecto donde genero documentos PDF y funciona muy bien en mi entorno de desarrollo, pero al momento de subirlo a producción me manda un error 500. Entre los logs del servidor encontré algo referente al css "Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: public/css/certificate.css". Lo agregue al vite.config.js pero sigue con el mismo error en producción.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/css/filament.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'public/css/certificate.css'

            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

La funcion que genera el pdf realmente lo hace bien.

```
            $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.certificate', compact(['product', 'user', 'date']))
                ->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            return $pdf->download('certificado.pdf');
```